# What's the equivalent of raise(SIGTRAP) in Linux kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, kernel, signals

I am developing a loadable Linux kernel module. I want to break the execution into a remote GDB debugger if the code encounters an unknown error.

Say, my module has a function as follows:

```
void hello()
{
    // ...
    if (something_occured)
    {
        // raise(SIGTRAP) or __asm__ __volatile__("int 3"); ???
        // What should be put here ??? 
    }
}
```

Can `raise(SIGTRAP)` be used in kernel mode. Is there the equivalence of `raise(SIGTRAP)` in kernel mode?

Answer (score 1):

What would you like your code to do if there IS no remote debugger running? Do that, and set a breakpoint on it.

It might be BUG, BUG_ON, or WARN_ON or a custom function of your own.

Comment: Under Windows kernel, there is a function DbgBreakPoint(); I just want the equivalent of it.

Comment: @xmllmx: What will you do if there isn't an equivalent?

Comment: I will use GDB's commands: break (pending) and continue in that case.